# Turntable Photography problem, Concerning set rotation and intervals.

Tags: trigonometry, rotations

For a project I have to take pictures of an object on a rotating turntable.

Setup is as follows:

- Camera with separate flashes are in front of a turntable taking pictures of a object on the turntable.
- I've got control over 1 input: The interval time at which the camera takes a picture.

**Problem**: I can't take a picture less than every 1.5 seconds (Camera and flashes can't keep up). But I want a picture at every +/- 10 degrees of rotation of the object.

**Question**: At what interval of time will I get pictures of the object with the difference in the rotation of the object +/- 10 degrees.

Given:

- Turntable is rotating constantly
- The turntable turns 720 degrees in 60 seconds.
- Photos can not be taken in an interval less then 1.5 seconds. (Camera and flashes can't    keep up).
- Arrangement of photos doesn't matter.

**I was thinking about taking a picture at X interval which will create a nice overlap in images after Y rotations.**

I'm absolutely no math wonder, So if anyone could help me that would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Do you mean "no _more_ than 12 degrees difference"?

Comment: I edited my question to make it more readable and understandble I hope.

Answer (score 1):

If you need *exactly* $10$ degrees between pictures, then you have to choose a degree separation that is (i) a multiple of $10$, and (ii) not a divisor of $360$ (otherwise you will just retake the same pictures after one revolution). The smallest number that satisfies (i) and (ii) is $50$. So you take a picture every $50$ degrees, i.e. every $4.1666...$ seconds. The whole shoot ($36$ pictures) takes five revolutions, or $150$ seconds.

If instead you just need *at most* $10$ degrees between pictures, you can get the thing done  in just two revolutions by shooting every $720/37 = 19.459459...$ degrees, i.e. every $1.621621..$ seconds. Your pictures ($37$ of them this time) will be separated by $360/37 = 9.729729...$ degrees.

Such methods require fairly accurate timing from both the turntable and the camera, but the second method is more robust. You might need to experiment with slightly different values to get the best results.

Comment: Thank you very much! For the answer and letting me understand the mathematics involved. I will as you say go and play a bit with these values to get the best result. Thanks.